# as well as vs like

Tags: word-choice

Can you help me with these two problems in this sentence?

**When I learnt that it could help raise money for stray animals, I made up my mind *like the other almost 50 participants.***

1. Doesn't **as well as** sound more appropriate than **like** here?
2. I can get what the author meant by **the other almost 50 participants** but it really looks weird to me. Is everything OK with this phrase?

Answer (score 1):

It is fine; they are using "like" with the meaning "the same as".

It could benefit from a comma after "mind", e.g. "... I made up my mind, like the other almost 50 participants."

No, "as well as" does not sound more appropriate. It would change the meaning. Because "I made up ..." is the action, so to say "I made up [my mind] as well as [the others]" means "I made up ... the almost 50 other participants."

It does not make sense. A stronger rewrite would be:

"When I learnt that it could help raise money for stray animals, I made up my mind. Much like the other almost 50 participants."